# how to split the repository history one line for each commit?

Tags: python, git, repository, git-log, mining

I'm trying to have the history of a repository, but the result is returned to me on a single line of text.

The command I'm using:

```
 cmd = f'git log --all --grep="fixed bug"'
```

The result I would like to have:

```
commit 337f4f4e798ea675cd57348212857ce051e857ffAuthor: Vinod...
commit 0b5a4823a963bd898b3979de8cce67513a1f83e5Author: Lofdw Kuma...
```

Comment: Check `git help log`, specifically the section about `--pretty` which will provide lots of options to suit your particular needs.

Comment: I tried checking `--pretty` but can't find a solution

Comment: So, something like `git log --pretty="Commit %H Author: %an"` does not work?

Comment: Always print on one line only

Comment: Do you have a single commit on that repo?

Comment: `Commit 337f4f4e798ea675cd57348212857ce051e857ff Author: Vinod Kumar VavilapalliCommit 0b5a4823a963bd898b3979de8cce67513a1f83e5 Author: Vinod Kumar VavilapalliCommit 2ecdc2b8a2b0156b9b2b34fca0447d3f2209918a`

Comment: All this text only prints to me on one line, I would like to split

Comment: There's a _special placeholder_ for new lines, explained in the section about `--pretty`. `%n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
git log --pretty="Commit: %H %nAuthor: %an"
```

- --pretty is the format you want it to have.
- %H is the commit hash.
- %an is the author name.
- The %n stands for newline.
- Everything in between is a string that you can form as you like.

This beautiful site has a lot of information about that topic:

https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats

Comment: With pretty format is it possible to also view files that have been changed since the commit?